# reset & fill grid c#

Tags: c#, image, grid, reset

i use a grid, that's content will often be changed.
in xaml it just looks like this:

```
 <Grid Name="grid1"/>
```

In C# I do this:

```
private void informGrid()
{
   grid1= new Grid();
   grid1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
   grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

   Canvas.SetZIndex(grid1, 51);

   grid1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
   grid1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

   grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(hw) });
   grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(hw) });

   grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition{ Width=new GridLength(hw)});
   grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition{ Width=new GridLength(hw)});
   grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition{ Width=new GridLength(hw)});
   grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition{ Width=new GridLength(hw)});
   grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition{ Width=new GridLength(hw)});

   fillGrid();
}
```

And then I add 10 images into this grid, in each cell 1 (100% working).
the grid becomes visible, has the right row&columndefinitons, 10 children, but the pictures aren't there.

i bet theres just a small mistake, but i wasn't able to find it.

please help me.
thanks.

Comment: the code for filling the grid with the images. tested before with diffenrent circumstances, worked 100%

Comment: `private void fillGrid()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Image blank = new Image();
                blank.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Images/blank.png");
                images.Add(blank);
                blank.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j); 
                blank.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, k);
                blank.Height = hw; 
                blank.Width = hw;
                grid1.Children.Add(blank);`

Comment: Are j and k initialized properly?

Comment: `int i= images.IndexOf(blank);
                int k = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Floor(ind / cpr));
                int j = ind % cpr;`
should work

Comment: Can you please check their i and k are all consistent. Also, what's the image HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment?

Comment: there are 10 images, the loop-i goes from 0-9, so i is always consistent. cpr is CountsPerRow, 5 this time. so k always consistent too. the alignments are untouched, so stretch, i guess.
EDIT: sorry, ind and i are the same above. my fault, only happend here, not in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used stackpanels instead, worked fine and you just have to clear the content

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the Images like :

```
Image yourImage = CreateImage(); //In Create image you return the image you want to display

grid1.Children.Add(yourImage);
```